# Different video colour on different screens - rgb values and CSS

Tags: css, html, video, colors

I have a webpage that I've put a background-color of #f4afac.

The video within this page also has the same background color (This video is mainly made up of the same color, all around it so blends in perfectly on the page, no edges).

On one screen it looks perfectly fine.

Another screen the colors are different shades. I understand that different screens display colors differently, but the issue is, is that if the colors are both the same in the video and the background-color of the page. Surely the screen should render the colors in the same way whether it's a video or not.

Answer (score 1):

After research, work arounds such as using canvas to get the color of the video at a px position proved to be messy solutions.

Instead, I created a 1 second video with the same color and used this as the background. The video color blends perfectly with the video in the background, each screen and computer both render the colors the same.

Due to the video in the background being 1 second (Wouldve made it shorter but minimum the video would export was 1 second) the file is very small.

That was the solution I used in the end that worked for me.